Is there a simpler astable multivibrator?
Can this one cell LED driver work as an astable multivibrator?

if so how is it compared to the Garner's Oscillator?

They look very similar, are they the same? Is the inductor coil playing a important role there? Sorry my lack of knowledge.
Do you know some variations that use only discrete components (no IC) but as few as possible compared to the conventional transistor astable multivibrator given I need only one oscillating output? Would it be more efficient giving less resistance and thus less heat?

P.S.: A found this detailed explanation that answer most of my doubts, is it the same Garner's Oscillator? I also found this other one but it's clearly stated to be the Garner's Oscillator. The only difference is that sometimes it have a inductor coil and sometimes it doesn't...
P.P.S.: I let the question open without mentioning what I'm building because it's mainly for learning purposes, what I'm building is a DC buck converter from 12V to 5V, but I'm very aware I could just buy a LM2596 and it would fit very well my goal, but I'd learn nothing from that!
Not an answer maybe
Here the summary of the information collected in the commentaries, I decided to not post as answer because I’m not confident enough but at least having it here could help people with similar doubts.
Here @Finbarr confirmed the shown one cell led driver is in fact a astable multivibrator.
Whether one cell led driver and Garner's oscillator are the same thing or not I think depends on the Garner definition, it's very likely the same, I’m just not confident enough to be sure.
@G32 pointed out it's possible to have even simpler solution using a NPN as negative resistor thought breakdown giving a example here even though they made clear it has some limitations.
@D.A.S. also pointed out it may be possible to have an oscillator using a Diac, maybe it would be a similar solution to the NPN breakdown.

Asking for as few components as possible is only beneficial for cost purposes but since there's no mention of target specifications, i.e. oscillation frequency and frequency/gain response, there's no clear recommendation we can provide.

@Colin you're right, having less components doesn't necessarily mean it's less complex, but I'd say that tends to be. The idea is not to be cheaper, it is just to eliminate waste, then maybe the better phrasing would be asking for efficiency comparison between the conventional transistor astable multivibrator with the garner's oscillator?

Does this count http://www.cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html  Google -  Single Transistor LED Flasher Circuit Using Negative Resistance

"Can this one cell LED driver work as an astable multivibrator?" Well, that's exactly what it is.

simpler is not a powerful spec without a purpose or specs like impedance, voltage, risetime, frequency etc.   But there are 2 pin devices that oscillate with bias and capacitance. Diac etc or Schmitt Trigger inverters.

@G36 very interesting to use the NPN as a negative resistor through breakdown, do you consider it risky or it's safe because it's for short time only?

@TiagoPimenta No risk, but reliability is the main problem, simply this circuit will not work with all NPN transistors and will never work with PNP transistors. And needs a high Vcc voltage of 12V. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361846/is-it-possible-to-make-current-flow-through-a-transistor-from-the-emitter-to-the/361855#361855

A single unijunction transistor (UJT) or programmable unijunction (PUT) can work as a relaxation oscillator.  So can a neon bulb.  So can a tunnel diode, but they are weird.
The most simple 1-device oscillator with a "normal" part uses a transistor's reverse breakdown characteristic to form a relaxation oscillator.

The schematic is from here:
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Relaxation-oscillator-circuit-with-a-transistor.php
AFAIK, Dick Cappels is the originator.
http://www.cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html

Do you know if ngspice is capable of simulating a NPN breakdown or it would be too much?

@TiagoPimenta The standard model structure cannot do it but Alex Bordodynov created some subcircuits that add the functionality: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/ltspice-avalanche-bjt-models.194193/

The Mad Russian strikes again.
